# add a custom button in ckeditor toolbar : uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token in javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

i want to add a custom button on a ckeditor toolbar. but it is giving me an error in a javascript that uncaught exception.my code of javascript is as below.

file name : `/ckeditor/plugins/linkbutton/plugin.js`

```
(function(){
    //Section 1 : Code to execute when the toolbar button is pressed
    var a= {
        exec:function(editor){
            var theSelectedText = editor.getSelection().getNative();
            CallCfWindow(theSelectedText);
        }
    },

    //Section 2 : Create the button and add the functionality to it
    b=’linkbutton’;
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b,{
        init:function(editor){
            editor.addCommand(b,a);
            editor.ui.addButton(‘linkbutton’,{
                label:’Link Button’,
                icon: this.path + ‘logo_ckeditor.png’,
                command:b
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

then in config.js file i have written this code,

```
config.extraPlugins = 'linkbutton';
config.toolbar_Full =  [['Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],['Link', 'Unlink'], ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'SelectAll', 'linkbutton']];
```

but it is not working and giving me an error in console.

Comment: I don't think we can help you until you don't tell us what kind error it is. This is the most important thing that you didn't mention ;)

Comment: I had already written that "uncaught exception" error is coming....in the first statement only...